# how to simpify this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (!errorHasHappened) {
    info.show();
    error.hide();
} else {
    info.hide();
    error.show();
}
```

I can't use toggle.

I tried to pass function show or hide to variable and then execute it, but it did not work for some reason and I got an JS error.

Comment: It looks to be about as simplified as it can get.

Comment: *"I can't use toogle."* Well, it's called `toggle`, but why not? You are not using jQuery 1.2, are you?

Comment: too bad, it looked like it could use a good toogle

Comment: I changed _toogle_ in _toggle_ (I hope was not this the problem), but may I know why you can't use toggle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
info[errorHasHappened?'hide':'show']();
error[errorHasHappened?'show':'hide']();
```

But that's the only option that I can think of, that makes the code shorter.

Code like that doesn't make it easier to maintain, though.

Comment: that is the point ;-) this code is written for people that know JS and it makes sense to use advance JS if you have a chance.

Answer (score 7):

You could do like this, but if statement is much clearer.

And why not use `.toggle` which is designed for such case?

```
info[errorHasHappened ? 'hide' : 'show']();
error[errorHasHappened ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

Comment: Post the same answer within seconds of each other, and the first one gets all the upvotes :/
Competition is brutal on SO :P (Still, +1 for being the faster gunman)

Comment: what if I call it with errorHasHappened=false and later with errorHasHappened=false. how will toggle works ?

Answer (score 1):

If making code shorter is your goal:

```
errorHasHappened?(info.hide(),error.show()):(info.show(),error.hide());
```

BTW, *making code shorter* `!==` *simplifying code*. IMO atleast..

Answer (score 1):

Anything that would make sense is to switch them around to prevent !

```
if (errorHasHappened) {
    info.hide();
    error.show();
} else {
    info.show();
    error.hide();
}
```

Comment: Technically, you reduced the code by one character, but this really should be a comment.

Comment: This is easier to maintain, as you might easily miss !.

Comment: While that is true, it doesn't change the fact this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How come it does not? It simplifies it exactly answering the question. (this is a rhetorical question, please do not answer).

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$( "#error" ).toggleClass( className, errorHasHappened);
$( "#info" ).toggleClass( className, errorHasHappened);
```

Comment: Combine the 2 jQuery selectors. As the answer is right now, it's more code.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't combine these 2 selectors with my limited jquery experince. Combining 2 **similar** selectors would make sense I believe.